# Weird behavior when hovering the hat without reaching the usercard trigger

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

Ok, this is me being nitpicky about it.

How to reproduce:

1. Leave the pointer over the hat (the div) without reaching the user pic/gravatar.
2. Said user should have >1k reputation and the usercard activated.

What happens:

The hat flicks repeatedly until you move the mouse away.

What should happen:

The hat should behave, or we send it back to the hat maker for fixing.

Where to find the bug easily, hover over my hat [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/391106/169736).

Comment: The problem seems to be that the hat before the usercard loads triggers the on hover, but then the hat disappears while the usercard expands, resulting in the initial event that triggered the usercard expanding to no longer be true (and thus, the card minimises again, the hats reappear under the mouse, and the expansion triggers again)

Comment: I was wondering how long it would take for someone to complain about this; you exceeded my expectations. Yeah, it's a known issue, and I'm not sure a care about it enough to fix for a few-weeks thing.

Comment: @balpha you are underestimating the capacity of SE folks? BTW, I was being nitpicky. ;)

Comment: @Flyk you make it sounds so complicated :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay okay, fair enough. This was actually an easy fix. It's working fine now.

Comment: It's Winter Season, show some more enthusiasm!

Comment: While I agree it's not at all a big deal for a transient event like this, I would put forth that no it totally isn't? I hover over your hat, it flickers exactly as described, right now. Firefox 27. :p

Comment: Ups, yeah, could reproduce here in meta.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ah, it's browser-specific. It works fine in Chrome, Opera, and Safari, but not Firefox and IE. I'll look at it.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Fixed; it now works correctly in FF and IE as well.

Comment: @Braiam see above

Comment: @neminem see above

Comment: @balpha Yep, now it works in FF.